# get value from database in string using query builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller, laravel-query-builder

so in controller I am getting a value from a input form in string i.e. product_name

```
return $request->input('product_name');
```

And on the behalf of this I want to get product_id of that product from database table using query builder

```
return category::where('product_name',$request->input('product_name'))->get('product_id');
```

problem is, I am getting the value in array form but i want this value in string

//output

> [{"product_id":7}]

but i want it in string like

> 7

please help to achieve this in single line using query builder, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `value` method to get a single value:

```
category::where('product_name', $request->input('product_name'))
    ->value('product_id')
```

[Laravel 5.8 Docs - Queries - Retrieving Results - Retrieving A Single Row / Column From A Table](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#retrieving-results) `value`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 return category::where('product_name',$request->input('product_name'))
->first()->pluck('product_id');
```

It looks like you want only one entry. For this you should use `first()` instead of `get()`.